# necessary condition for the existence of the posterior mean

Tags: bayesian, mean, moments

I wonder if there exists results relating properties of the prior and the likelihood to the existence of the posterior mean (or more generally to the posterior moments). Any hint or sufficiant condition will be also appreciate.

Comment: why downvoting?